# Intellisense deleting code as I type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper, intellisense

Intellisense (or Resharper) is occasionally deleting my C# code as I write it. It's occuring in declarations and in method calls, and seems to be triggered by a comma or open bracket. The Undo history shows the erroneous action simply as "Intellisense". What could be causing such behaviour?

I managed to reproduce one of these unhelpful deletions here:

[image]

I'm running VS 2015 Professional Update 3 with ReSharper 2016.3.1

EDIT: I passed this issue on to JetBrains, it's categorised as a critical bug [on YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-463177)

Comment: 4 votes? Where's the Resharper hate coming from?

Comment: Odd, Im assuming you've tried restarting? You may need to uninstall/reinstall ReSharper.

Comment: In VS, select **Tools.Options.Resharper** and click **Suspend Now**;  click **OK** and try again.  You'll soon know if it's Resharper

Comment: If after the above, the problem `only occurs with ReSharper enabled`, please post a screenshot for your settings for **ReSharper.Options.Environment.Intellisense.General** to assist us

Comment: Thanks, suspending Resharper did seem to fix the issue. Under ReSharper.Options.Environment.Intellisense.General I have Intellisense set to "ReSharper"

Comment: Thanks.   With that confirmed, your best action now is to contact JetBrains Tech Support

Comment: @DavidH, if you set the ReSharper.Options.Environment.Intellisense.General to 'Visual Studio', does this issue disappear? If so, like MickyD said, you can redirect to the resharper support forum:https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366389-ReSharper-Community for a professional support for this issue. If you already report this issue to Resharper, would you mind sharing the link or the schedule as a reply? So, other community members who meet the same issue can know the detail information, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what causes this, but it happened to me today and yesterday as well, with 2016.3.2, and to fix it I downloaded and reinstalled ReSharper.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem in the Resharp-Installer for some "version-combinations". I talked to the Tech-Support about this.
What's happening is basically the Resharper-Installation gets corrupted and sets some key-shortcuts for the wrong buttons.
In your case a ',' deletes the whole word in front it seems.
They're still unsure about which combinations lead to these problems and why. They told me to whether update my Visual Studio and reinstall Resharper, or use an older version of Resharper.